# Wordpress Plugins Loaded Multiple Times

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I'm apparently misunderstanding something very basic.

I'm developing a plugin (but I've checked on commercial ones also).  For debug purposes, I write to a log file when the plug-in loads.  I find that I write the same message multiple times, indicating that I'm going through the loading code multiple times.

I've disabled all my custom plugins (deactivate, not uninstall) and checked and a commercial plugin (MAXBUTTONS) shows as loading 6 times.

Since I can't find other reports of something like this, I presume I'm doing something silly, but I'm at a loss as to how to find it.

Has anyone seen something like this?  Ideas on what to look for?

Thanks,
    --Don

Answer (score 0):

This just happened to me. I tried disabling parts of my code until i found the culprit - i had several enqueued files (via wp_enqueue_style and wp_enqueue_script), but the enqueued files didn't exist yet. Once i put them in their place, the mutiple loading stopped.